# How to access ear's Manifest file from the class present in web app?

Tags: java, manifest, ear

I want to access a property defined in an EAR's manifest file from a class which is present in the web app positioned within the ear. Is there any way to access that. Currently, I am using the following code by passing a property name/value to access the correct manifest file and then I will add more code to get the value for my desired property.

```
public static Manifest getManifest(Class<?> cls, String entryName, String entryValue) throws IOException
{
    Manifest retManifest = null;
    boolean matchFound = false;
    Class<?> srcClass = cls == null ? this.class : cls;
    Enumeration<URL> resources = srcClass.getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

    while (resources.hasMoreElements() && matchFound == false)
    {
        URL u = resources.nextElement();
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(u.openStream());
        if (manifest != null)
        {
            Attributes atr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
            if (atr != null && atr.keySet() != null)
            {
                Iterator<Object> atrIr = atr.keySet().iterator();
                while (atrIr.hasNext() && matchFound == false)
                {
                    Object atrKey = atrIr.next();
                    if (atrKey != null && atrKey.toString().equals(entryName))
                    {
                        if (atr.get(atrKey) != null && atr.get(atrKey).toString().equals(entryValue))
                        {
                            retManifest = manifest;
                            matchFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return retManifest;
}
```

My problem is that code is running fine and scans all manifests from various jar files but it somehow donot find the Manifest file present under ear's META-INF folder. Can somebody help me in finding the same.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [EAR file format on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format))

==============>>>>
The META-INF directory contains at least the application.xml deployment descriptor, known as the Java EE Deployment Descriptor. It contains the following XML entities:

icon, which specifies the locations for the images that represent the application. A subdivision is made for small-icon and large-icon.
display-name, which identifies the application
description
A module element for each module in the archive
Zero or more security-role elements for the global security roles in the application
Each module element contains an ejb, web or java element which describes the individual modules within the application. Web modules also provide a context-root which identifies the web module by its URL.

There's no MANIFEST.MF in ear's META-INF directory that is being looked upon in the program.