# ServletContext getResourceAsStream does not return root Manifest Files

Tags: java, maven, servlets, war, manifest.mf

This might be a duplicate question, but after trying almost all the possible solutions, I am still unable to read the correct manifest file in my war.
here is how my war file looks like;

> - META-INF
>
>   - maven/com.abc.pack/console
>   - MANIFEST.MF
>   - context.xml
> - WEB-INF
>
>   - classes    com.abc    -configurations
>       -MainController
>   - lib   -(multiple jars)

I want to access /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF at the root from the MainController class .

**Used**

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

and

```
this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Both return null.

Tried several other solutions provided but it then read manifest file of the one of jars inside the lib folder but not the root.

Some solution also had the jcabi plugin to use read manifest but i want to try without a plugin support.

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Here  is a duplicate question but cannot determine solution from answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/34289754/3248320

Comment: Resolved. Above method is correct and My code was unable to fetch it since i was deploying the exploded war folders which did not contain manifest. The actual war when deployed generates this manifest file and is accessible using above methods.